# Explanation for Booth's Algorithm for Lexicographically minimal string rotation

Tags: algorithm

Can someone please explain or comment me this code for Booth's Algorithm for Lexicographically minimal string rotation from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation#Booth.27s_Algorithm)?

```
def least_rotation(S: str) -> int:
    """Booth's algorithm."""
    S += S  # Concatenate string to it self to avoid modular arithmetic
    f = [-1] * len(S)  # Failure function
    k = 0  # Least rotation of string found so far
    for j in range(1, len(S)):
        sj = S[j]
        i = f[j - k - 1]
        while i != -1 and sj != S[k + i + 1]:
            if sj < S[k + i + 1]:
                k = j - i - 1
            i = f[i]
        if sj != S[k + i + 1]:  # if sj != S[k+i+1], then i == -1
            if sj < S[k]:  # k+i+1 = k
                k = j
            f[j - k] = -1
        else:
            f[j - k] = i + 1
    return k
```

I am lost with the indices and the k etc. What does it mean, why is there [j - k - 1] indexing etc.?
Thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article says "The correctness of the algorithm is somewhat difficult to understand." You'll probably have to read Booth's paper (also linked from Wikipedia) to understand what it does.

Comment: It's easier to understand if you start with the KMP algorithm. Personally, I prefer Duval's algorithm based on Lyndon factoring.